# python pandas function return multiple values and put them into columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, return-value

i have two functions as below. The second one works but the first one doesn't work. Why?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

def add_subtract_list(a, b):
  return [1,2,3,4]
add_subtract_list(5,8)

df[['c','d','x','y']] = df.apply(
    lambda row: add_subtract_list(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
```

below function works. It is from [this](https://apassionatechie.wordpress.com/2017/12/27/create-multiple-pandas-dataframe-columns-from-applying-a-function-with-multiple-returns/) page

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})



def add_subtract_list(a, b):
  return [a + b, a - b]

df[['sum', 'difference']] = df.apply(
    lambda row: add_subtract_list(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Update your function such that it returns a pandas Series instead of a python list.

```
def add_subtract_list(a, b):
  return pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: any idea why i have to use pandas series when i am returning 4 elements? pandas series is not required if i am returning 2 elements!

Comment: Actually, No. I don't know how pandas can split these values into multiple columns.

Comment: could you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011830/pandas-function-return-multiple-values-error - it is very similar