# pandas function return multiple values error - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, pandas, function, return

I have written a pandas function and it runs fine (the second last line of my code). When i try to assign my function's output to columns in dataframes i get an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

i posted a something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010434/python-pandas-function-return-multiple-values-and-put-them-into-columns) and i am using method shown in the answer of that question in the below function. But still it fails :(

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def benford_function(value):
    if value == '':
        return []

    if ("." in value):
         before_decimal=value.split(".")[0]
         if len(before_decimal)==0:
             bd_first="0"
             bd_second="0"

         if len(before_decimal)>1:
             before_decimal=before_decimal[:2]
             bd_first=before_decimal[0]
             bd_second=before_decimal[1]
         elif len(before_decimal)==1:
             bd_first="0"
             bd_second=before_decimal[0]

         after_decimal=value.split(".")[1]
         if len(after_decimal)>1:
             ad_first=after_decimal[0]
             ad_second=after_decimal[1]
         elif len(after_decimal)==1:
             ad_first=after_decimal[0]
             ad_second="0"
         else:
             ad_first="0"
             ad_second="0"



    else:
        ad_first="0"
        ad_second="0"
        if len(value)>1:
             bd_first=value[0]
             bd_second=value[1]
        else:
            bd_first="0"
            bd_second=value[0]
    return pd.Series([bd_first,bd_second,ad_first,ad_second])



df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': ["123"]})


df.apply(lambda row: benford_function(row['a']), axis=1)

df[['bd_first'],['bd_second'],['ad_first'],['ad_second']]= df.apply(lambda row: benford_function(row['a']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
df[['bd_first'],['bd_second'],['ad_first'],['ad_second']] = ...
```

to

```
df[['bd_first', 'bd_second', 'ad_first', 'ad_second']] = ...
```

This will fix your type-error, since index elements must be hashable. The way you tried to index into the Dataframe by passing a tuple of single-element lists will interpret each of those single element lists as indices